# How to find PhD co-supervisor?

Tags: phd, supervision, business-school

I am looking for a co-supervisor to assist me during my research journey based on online / remote supervision.
Does anyone knows how I can make an ad or search for such a thing?

---

I would prefer to find him myself and to avoid my supervisor assistant since I know that he would not be helpful to do so.

Do you know nay website that I can find some ?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a supervisor, ask him first, he would need to agree either way and might have some ideas or contacts. If you don't have a supervisor yet, look for one before thinking about co-supervisors.